Debugging Coral Acclerator not found in `lspci` output
I have a mini PCIe Coral Accelerator. I've plugged it in to my Pi using a Pineboards Hat AI! with the FPC connector. Having installed the drivers following the Getting Started guide, I can't find the card in the output of lspci.
I've checked the FPC connector.
Does this mean that the card is not connected physically to the device?
Could it still be the driver?
Is there any way to tell between hardware connection and driver not loading?

So I started from scratch and went back to the instructions.
I had checked the FPC connector but I had the board in upside down.
The Coral Accelerator should be facing the Pi. You will know if the FPC connector is powering the Pineboards board as there is an LED on there that should illuminate if correctly sited.
